# Is it safe to cast away const if never call any non-const methods

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, constants, undefined-behavior

Is it still undefined behavior to cast away const from a pointer to an object if only const methods are ever be called after the cast?

I'm trying to implement both an iterator and const_iterator for a class where the dereferenced iterator is a proxy object with a small amount of state and a pointer to the parent object (simplified below)

Although the const qualified proxy only calls const methods on the parent it still requires a non-const pointer in the constructor.

```
class query {
   public:
      int  get (int r, int c) const;
      void set (int r, int c, int v);

      class iterator {
         iterator (query *q, int r) : m_qry(q), m_row(r) {}
         row operator* const () { return row(m_qry, m_row); }

         query *m_qry;
         int m_row;
      };

      class const_iterator {
         const_iterator (const query *q, int r) : m_qry(q), m_row(r) {}

         const row operator* const () {
            // protected constructor for row needs cast
            return row(const_cast<query *>(m_qry), m_row);
         }

         const query *m_qry;
         int m_row;
      };

      iterator       begin() { return iterator(this, 0); }
      const_iterator begin() { return const_iterator(this, 0); }
};

class row {
   friend query;

   public:
      int get (int col) const {
         // can be called by both row and const row
         return m_qry->get(m_row, col);
      }

      void set (int col, int v) {
         // cannot be called for const row
         return m_qry->set(m_row, col, v);
      } 

   protected:
      row (query *q, int row) : m_qry(q), m_row(r) {}

   private:
      query *m_qry;
      int m_row;
};
```

I would prefer to avoid using different classes for the differing iterators as this would require considerable code duplication.

If this is not possible are there any other alternative design patterns with good performance?

Comment: however with the above design the compiler will bite you via the default copy constructor accepting a const reference and producing a non-const object

Answer (score 2):

In a const method, the `this` pointer is a const type.

So given that it's implicitly cast back to const, the behaviour is well defined.